# How to convert html into PDF in angular 6 when using binding

Tags: angular, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I converted html to PDF in angular but the problem is I am using binding to display all the list. I am using list view in loop the PDF convert only one list view it cannot convert whole list into PDF.How to achieve this?

pdf.ts:

```
export class PDFComponent{

 @ViewChild('content') content:ElementRef;
  test:any;

 downloadPdf() {
  let doc= new jspdf();
  let specialElememtHandlers = {
    '#editor':function(element,renderer)
    {
      return true;
    }    
  };
  let content =this.content.nativeElement;
  doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML,15,15, {
    'width':190,
    'elementHandlers':specialElememtHandlers
  });
  doc.save('test.pdf');
  }
}
```

pdf.html:

```
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white m-b-10 p-l-5" (click)="downloadPDF()"></button>
<ul class="result-list" *ngFor="let reg of test
        id="content" #content>
        <li>
          <div class="result-price" style="background:center #2d353c;color: #fff;">
            <h3 style="color: #fff">{{reg.id}}</h3>
            <h4 style="color: #fff">{{reg.date}}</h4>
            <p>
              <small>
                <b>{{reg.implication}}</b>
              </small>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="result-info">
            <h4 class="title">
              {{reg.title}}
            </h4>
            <br>
            <p class="desc">
              <b>Summary:</b> {{reg.desc}}
            </p>    
             </div>             
        </li>          
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your ngFor loop duplicate element `<ul id="content">` in result you have multiple elements with the same id. Then You want to get content of element by this duplicated id. It will give you only the first found on the page.

Try to wrap your loop in div element and get content of this div.

Comment: I reproduced your's code replacing ViewChild by injecting reference to element in constructor and it works. Maybe it will help you achieve your goals.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dw5wmw

Comment: Hey Its Working.But I want to convert only certain details into PDF.The above code convert the whole page details into PDF